# Tracking UIScrollview contentoffset - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, contentoffset

I have a scrollview with frame smaller than the contentsize. The scrollview is paging enabled. This is similar to the safari new tab page in iOS Safari app. My question is "I have 4 images A,B,C and D. If B is inside the frame is it possible for me know what objects that are not within the frame?" Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpCkY.png) for the implemented UIScrollview. The black box with low alpha component is to be replaced by blurry effect on the other pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try implementing the delegate methods;  scrollviewdidscroll or scrollviewdidenddecelerating? Here you can simply get the scrollview.contentoffset.